# JOOQ Creating table with indices

Tags: java, sql, jooq

As per documentation in order to create a table with JOOQ:

```
context.createTable("table")
      .column("column1", INTEGER)
      .column("column2", VARCHAR(10).nullable(false))
      .constraints(
          primaryKey("column1"),
          unique("column2"),
          foreignKey("column2").references("some_other_table"),
          check(field(name("column2")).like("A%"))
      )
      .execute();
```

However, it seems like that it's also possible to declare indices at table creation:

```
context.createTable("table")
      .column("column1", INTEGER)
      .column("column2", VARCHAR(10).nullable(false))
      .constraints(
          primaryKey("column1"),
          unique("column2"),
          foreignKey("column2").references("some_other_table"),
          check(field(name("column2")).like("A%"))
      )
      .indexes(...indices)
      .execute();
```

I can't find anything in documentation explaining how to do that.

What is a proper way to declare indicies this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular syntax is not yet supported by jOOQ 3.15:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9243

You can implement it yourself in various ways, e.g.:

- Using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)
- Using [execute listeners](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-execute-listeners/)

Alternatively, you can run two separate statements using the jOOQ DSL API:

- `CREATE TABLE`
- `CREATE INDEX`